# Prevent nearby text selection on inline svg click

Tags: html, css, svg, inline-svg

When using an inline SVG as a clickable element, clicking it twice may select nearby text.

How can this be prevented without forcing user-select on all nearby elements?

```css
.wrap {
  height: 100px;
}
.icon {
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: bounding-box;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <svg class="icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 136 136">
    <defs/>
    <path fill="none" stroke="rgb(160,70,255)" stroke-width="3" d="M68 134.43A66.43 66.43 0 101.5 68 66.46 66.46 0 0068 134.43zM123.77 68H12.23M68 12.3v111.41"/>
  </svg>
</div>
<div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
```

Comment: it's not the click on the SVG but the click on the whole container (try to click on the right of the SVG)

Comment: I see, but still how to avoid it ?

Comment: Seems to be some kind of Chrome bug. Report it to Chrome's bugtracker.

Comment: Thanks @RobertLongson in light of the previous comment, wouldn't this actually be unrelated to svg?

Comment: I've no idea, you could try to create different testcases to find out I guess.

Comment: just put user-select:none on the wrap only... you can still select everything else..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you mean? ( Added user-select: none; )

```css
.wrap {
  height: 100px;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;

}
.icon {
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: bounding-box;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <svg class="icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 136 136">
    <defs/>
    <path fill="none" stroke="rgb(160,70,255)" stroke-width="3" d="M68 134.43A66.43 66.43 0 101.5 68 66.46 66.46 0 0068 134.43zM123.77 68H12.23M68 12.3v111.41"/>
  </svg>
</div>
<div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
```

Comment: Yes! that makes perfect sense, of course. If the icon wrapper element does not allow selecting, the selection does not spill to nearby elements. That's great thank you!